# Django: Is it reasonable to use objects as dictionary keys?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, key

Is it reasonable to use objects as keys to a dictionary in django?  I have done so and it works. But I am wondering if this is best practice, or if it is going to make difficulties I don't foresee right now.

I am working on a project which deals with educational standards.  I have dictionaries with a structure along the lines of `{Subject:[Standards]}`.  The model for subject looks something like:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
  subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.subject
```

Is it okay to use the objects from this model as keys to my dictionaries, or should I be using a string represenation, such as Subject.subject instead?

If so, does the unicode method affect this?  When I tried using Subject.subject as the key, I got things like `{u'Math': [<Subject: Students can perform calculations.>]}`  Using objects as keys, it looks like `{<Subject: Math>: [<Standard: Students can perform calculations.>]}`

This is a followup to a question I asked yesterday about [using None as a dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030029/python-is-it-reasonable-to-use-none-as-a-dictionary-key).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mutable objects shouldn't really be used as dictionary keys. That said, this works because the base model class defines `__hash__` in terms of the model's primary key, which is unlikely to change. But I would prefer to use the pk directly as the key.

Comment: Is this as simple as `def __hash__(self): return self.id`?  If so, why does that need to be made explicit?  Or do you mean I should define my dictionaries as `{subject.id:[standard.id]}`?

Comment: This has the same idea as Alexandru's response, but is a little more specific.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you want to use them. I'd suggest a simpler approach though:

The keys of the dictionaries could be the Model's primary key.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the objects implement a good hash function I'd say that there's nothing wrong with using objects as keys, but that is just my personal opinion.

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to use string representation since, when you will need to do looks up you will need to write out all that stuff, which will be a pain, plus if in the future you want to change your unicode representation you will have to find a way of rewriting the old unicode to do look ups.

Goodluck.